# How can i play video by getting Video from PhotoLibrary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I am doing an app on ipad,Which will capture video and it will save in photo Library. But what i want is i want to play that video choosing from the photo library  and need to play over there.I saw many examples using `MPMoviePlayerController` but all i saw is they adding video over there and they playing that video.Is there any way to write path for my below mentioned code.
My code goes here

This where i calling Photo library

```
-(IBAction) goToPhotos:(id)sender {

    ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    ipc.delegate = self;
    ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    ipc.allowsEditing = YES;
    UIPopoverController *videoController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:ipc];
    //    pop.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 900);
    [videoController presentPopoverFromRect:[sender frame] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
    [ipc release];  
    [self presentModalViewController:ipc animated:YES];

}
```

Here i am calling `MPMoviePlayerController` .Code goes here

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{    
    NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                     pathForResource:@"Stock_Footage_Demobroadband"
                     ofType:@"mp4"];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:[playerViewController moviePlayer]];

    [self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];

    //---play movie---
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [playerViewController moviePlayer];
    [player play];

    [super viewDidLoad];    
}

- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:player];
    [player stop];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [player autorelease];    
}
```

Can any one tell me how can i get path for photolibrary and i need to play video over there.

```
 NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                         pathForResource:@"Stock_Footage_Demobroadband"
                         ofType:@"mp4"];
```

Can we modify this line and is there any way that i can get path to photo library so that i can play video over there. Help me Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the delegate methods for UIImagePickerController.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSURL *movieURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

   MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: movieURL];
   //finish implementing the movie player controller

}
```

Comment: Can u tell me can we change this line and is there any way that we can write path for photo library by replacing this line

Comment: NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                         pathForResource:@"Stock_Footage_Demobroadband"
                         ofType:@"mp4"];

Comment: The only way to access the photo library is with UIImagePickerController. The above code will give you the URL to the video the user selected. Here's a link to the documentation for UIImagePickerController. If this isn't working you haven't implemented it correctly. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007069